# Is it acceptable to edit a question and modify its original context?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

I want to know if I've understood the original question correctly and if the 2nd edit made to the OP has changed the context to make my answer incorrect?

[How to apply lock to 2 functions in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15494805/1572595)

**What has happened**

The original question (with typos fixed) was

> "so that the 1st function gets executed 1st and then the second
>   function executes when called simultaneously."

I thought a grammatical edit would result in

> "so that the 1st function gets executed 1st and then the second
>   function executes, when called simultaneously."

**How I understood the edit history**

However the 2nd edit and changed the original question to

> "How to apply a lock to 2 functions so that the 1st function gets
>   executed 1st and then the second function executes simultaneously when
>   called."

This has effectively changed the question from asking

> 'How can I call one javascript function after another, even though
>   they are both called simulaneously'

to

> 'How can I call two javascript functions simutaneously'

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't see anything in those edits that changes the meaning of the question. It's only formatting and typo fixes.

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevant occurrences included, is my understanding wrong and is this a legitimate edit?

Comment: Honestly, after re-reading all that, I don't see a change in meanings, **but** I don't understand the question either in any of its forms.

Comment: I agree, even if not radical change as you say that second edit is too minor, I rolled it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the question to:

- fix gramatical errors.
- reformat the question to make it better readable.
- retag the question

You can not change the meaning of the question. Altough you can change the wording, if it makes the question more clear.

Be sure to address all the issues in a post if you start editing.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer specific to the context of the SO question I linked, thanks for clarifying the edit rule though.

Comment: @ZebRawnsley Well, it doesn't seem to be hard to apply that rule to this question.  It's clearly changing the meaning of the question, not improving how it's worded, so it is invalid.  Perhaps the reader just mis-understood the question and thought they were clarifying it, not changing it.  Just because the edit was wrong doesn't mean it was malicious.  The edit was rolled back, all is good.

Answer (score 0):

edit should not change meaning  of question

> [**When should I edit posts?**](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit)
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

Comment: In some cases, the only way a user can get question unbanned is to modify their questions such that the original question is no longer what's being asked. What does your solution say to do that in this case?  Also: That's referring to edits *by other people*.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker In this case the edit *was* done by another user, and not the OP.  My guess is someone mis-understood the question, and they thought they were making an ambigious case clear, when in fact they were changing it's meaning.

Comment: @Servy Ah, my mistake; when I read the original question it seemed like he was saying the OP changed his own question.